# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}\,3^{(1-\sec^220x)/(\sec^210x-1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, indeterminate-forms

I want to evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to0}\;3^{(1-\sec^220x)/(\sec^210x-1)}$$

So far these have been my ideas, feel free to correct me:

1. Find that if directly applied to the function, $x_0$ will cause indetermination.
2. Manipulate the function trigonometrically, since $\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$, giving me:
   $1-\frac{1}{\cos^220x}$ and $\frac{1}{\cos^210x}-1$ respectively in the numerator and denominator of the exponent.
3. Apply the property $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}a^{f(x)}=a^{\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)}$
4. Then apply the property that allows me to split the limit of f/g(x) into \lim f(x)/\lim g(x)
5. This is the last step I thought of, finding the LMC.

I'm not sure where to go now, so I'd appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1 - \sec^2(20x)}{\sec^2(10x) - 1} &= \frac{\cos^2(20x) - 1}{1 - \cos^2(10x)} \times \frac{\cos^2(10x)}{\cos^2(20x)} \\
&= -\frac{\sin^2(20x)}{\sin^2(10x)} \times \frac{\cos^2(10x)}{\cos^2(20x)} & \sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1\\
&= -\frac{4\sin^2(10x)\cos^2(10x)}{\sin^2(10x)} \times \frac{\cos^2(10x)}{\cos^2(20x)} & \sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\\
&=-\frac{4\cos^4(10x)}{\cos^2(20x)}
\end{align*}$$